# How to render custom font in HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I saw a code pen here for rendering Microsoft Fabric UI Icons in a canvas in code pen. This is the working link

https://codepen.io/joshmcrty/pen/GOBWeV

There is a lot of extra stuff here to customize it. So I attempted to minimize this to barebones. What I did is completely remove the css, change the HTML to just the canvas tag, and reduced the JS code. The result looks like this:

HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="92" height="92"></canvas>
```

CSS

```
/*none*/
```

JS

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");


function getFontIconCharacter(className, pseudo = ':before') {
  var testI = document.createElement('i');
  var char;

  testI.className = `ms-Icon ms-Icon--${className}`;
  document.body.appendChild(testI);

  char = window.getComputedStyle(testI, pseudo).getPropertyValue('content').replace(/'|"/g, '');

  testI.remove();
  return char;
}


function drawRect() {
  context.fillStyle = "#777777";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function drawIcon() {

  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawRect();
  context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
                let fontClass = "Contact",
                  fontSize = 56,
                  topOffset = 46,
                  leftOffset = 46;
  context.font = fontSize + "px FabricMDL2Icons";
  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.textBaseline = "middle";
  context.fillText(getFontIconCharacter(fontClass), parseInt(leftOffset, 10), parseInt(topOffset, 10));
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  drawIcon();
});
```

The weird thing is if I replace the code from the working example into the above, the custom font in the canvas still renders correctly. However if I recreate it on a new file, it does not render the font properly. I saved my attempt here

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Fabric UI Icons</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/11.0.0/css/fabric.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="92" height="92"></canvas>
        <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            
            function getFontIconCharacter(className, pseudo = ':before') {
                var testI = document.createElement('i');
                var char;

                testI.className = `ms-Icon ms-Icon--${className}`;
                document.body.appendChild(testI);

                char = window.getComputedStyle(testI, pseudo).getPropertyValue('content').replace(/'|"/g, '');

                testI.remove();
                return char;
            }
            function drawCircle() {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
                var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
                var radius = canvas.width / 2;
                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                context.fillStyle = "#777777";
                context.fill();
            }
            function drawRect() {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                context.fillStyle = "#777777";
                context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            }
            function drawIcon() {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                drawRect();
                context.fillStyle = "#ffffff"; // icon color
                let fontClass = "Contact",
                  fontSize = 56,
                  topOffset = 46,
                  leftOffset = 46;
                context.font = fontSize + "px FabricMDL2Icons";
                context.textAlign = "center";
                context.textBaseline = "middle";
                context.fillText(getFontIconCharacter(fontClass), parseInt(leftOffset, 10), parseInt(topOffset, 10));
            }
            
            window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                drawIcon();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I noticed they include a css file to the font, so I have that as well, but it still doesn't work.

Does anyone see what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I had to start the font loading process with this. Just because it's defined in a `<link>` tag doesn't mean it will start loading. Something needs to reference it before its used on the canvas for the browser to load it.

```
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: FabricMDL2Icons;
        }
    </style>
```